# How to get AngularJS to perform a calculation inside a template?

Tags: angularjs

The script below does not perform the calculation `{{ 5+ 15 }}`, it just returns "5+ 15" as seen in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEStA.png)

HTML:

```
  <html>
    <head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  <title></title>
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  
  <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="starter">
  <ion-pane>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">
        <div style="color:#FF00FF" align="center">Ionic Testing</div>
      </h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <div ng-app="FirstModule" ng-controller="myFirstControl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="FirstName" name="FirstName">
        <input type="text" ng-model="SecondName">
        <span ng-bind="FirstName"></span> Full Name: {{ 5+ 15 }}
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any error messages in console?

Comment: you have two ng-app in your html

Comment: Thank's Mohan Gopi. Now Working Perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I just edited your question and noticed that you have ng-app declared twice:

There is one on the `<body>` tag and another on the first `<div>` inside `<ion-content>`.

Remove one of these (doesn't matter which) and your calculation should work as expected.